# "weight" and "weigh"

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms, ambiguity

It seems to me that both 'weight' and 'weigh'  can be used  metaphorically.

[en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/weight](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/weight)

> I think it's important to recognize the cost of war and to weight that cost against our raison d'être.’
>
> Thus, two countries with vastly different populations, like Ghana and China, for example, are weighted equally.

[sentence.yourdictionary.com/weigh](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/weigh)

> Common bowling alleys are privy moths that eat up the credit of many idle citizens; whose gains at home are not able to weigh down their losses abroad; whose shops are so far from maintaining their play, that their wives and children cry out for bread, and go to bed supperless often in the year.
>
> to weigh one thing against another, a term applied in English law to a number of different forms of legal reparation;

What is the difference?

Comment: “to assign a value of importance to” vs “to take measure of”

Comment: Using *weight* in place of *weigh* as in *… recognize the cost of war and to weight that* is clearly archaic and even then, was more poetic than anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Weighting* is something we do to adjust the proportional contribution of something. We apply a weighting factor to modify something's relative importance. Eg. in the cardboard canoe building contest, the race score was weighted higher than the presentation score and team cheer score when calculating the final score.

*Weighing* implies a direct comparison of things, just like on a pan balance.  After weighing the options, we decided to skip the cardboard canoe building contest this year and go visit some friends.

Weighting means to adjust something's importance.
Weighing means to assess something's importance.

In your first example for *weight* - "and to weight that cost against" - *weight* means to make a direct comparison to some other thing, as if placing it on a pan balance already containing the other thing. But it is a very rare usage. "and weigh that cost against" would be the normal way to say it.

In your first example for *weigh* - "not able to weigh down" - *[weigh down](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weigh_down)* is a [phrasal verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_phrasal_verbs_with_particle_(down)) with a distinct meaning. It doesn't really fit your question.

Comment: Thanks: your 'adjust' vs. 'assess' made everything crystal-clear.

Answer (score 0):

One weighs matters in the mind, balancing them in thought.

> First weigh the considerations, then take the risks.
>   Helmuth von Moltke (1800 - 1891)

But some things in life are a weight on the spirit, burdensome.

> One word frees us of all the weight and pain of life: That word is love.
>   Sophocles (496 BC - 406 BC)

Both quotations from :

> http://www.quotationspage.com