# to weigh or to weight

Tags: meaning

I am a bit confused regarding what is the correct way to say that we adjust a value according to some factor.

What is the correct way to write the following sentence:

> A number between 0-1 indicates how to **weight** the value when calculating the final score.

or

> A number between 0-1 indicates how to **weigh** the value when calculating the final score.

Comment: If you're thinking in terms of calculating a "weighted average", then "weight" is the word to use.  If you're thinking in terms of judging the values (for how accurate they are or whether they're worthy of inclusion in whatever you're doing, for example), then "weigh" is the word to use.

Comment: In the case of this sentence, _weight_ is the only word that makes sense. _Weigh_ in this context simply means 'think about', and a number between 0 and 1 does not indicate anything about how to do that. Whereas such a number is useful as a weighting factor.

Comment: The train car was weighed by a scale under the track.  The car was weighted by a load of coal.

Comment: I can see both *weigh* and *weight* being applicable here, but unless you tell us what you're trying to say in other words, it is impossible for us to know which meaning is intended: to *weigh* (to determine how heavy or important something is) or to *weight* (to assign a level of heaviness or importance to something).

Comment: Related: [“weight” and “weigh”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/413210/weight-and-weigh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, both the verb and the noun are *weight*, while *weigh* would involve measuring how heavy something or someone is

Suppose we have two classes of children, one with 20 children and the other with 30 children.  We *weigh* the children to find out how heavy they are, and discover the average *weight* in the first class is 40kg, while the average *weight* in the second class is 60kg

To find the average *weight* across all 50 children, we can take the [*weighted* average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean).  One way is to use the *weights* of 20/50 = 0.4 for the first class and 30/50 = 0.6 for the second class, so getting a result of (0.4*40) + (0.6*60) = 52kg